# JSF: How to replace "\\" in a string

Tags: java, regex, string, jsf-2, el

Suppose I have the string `text\\`, I need to replace `\\` with `/`. I tried the following expression:

```
/*  str = "text\\"  */
<h:outputText value="#{fn:replace(str, '\\', '/')}" />
```

But I always run into the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
^
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1671)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1337)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1022)
at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2210)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.fn.JstlFunction.replace(JstlFunction.java:222)
```

I'd be very grateful if you could give me an advice.

**UPDATE:** Based on the answers below, I found out that the following expression will work:

```
<h:outputText value="#{fn:replace(str, '\\\\', '/')}" />
```

Best regards,

Comment: you want output of text\\ as text// or text/ ?

Comment: @FahimParkar: I'd like it to be `text/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (haven't checked....)

```
<ui:param name="mydouble" value="\\\\"></ui:param>
<ui:param name="mysingle" value="/"></ui:param>
<h:outputText value="#{fn:replace(str, mydouble, mysingle)}" />
```

Comment: I have just tried your solution. It resulted in the same exception :(.

Comment: what namespace are you using ? `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core` ? is it JSF 2 app ?

Comment: I'm sorry. It's working. I made some mistake while testing :D. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to escape the backslashes. Try this: `replace("\\\\", "/")`

```
public class BackSlashEscaper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "text\\\\";
        System.out.println(text);

        System.out.println(text.replace("\\\\", "/"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
text\\
text/
```

Comment: He needs to replace **2** not 1 backslash.

Comment: > Suppose I have the string text\\, I need to replace \\ with /.

Comment: Sorry, I need a solution that will work in an EL expression :(.

Comment: The JSTL `fn:replace()` uses `String#replaceAll()` under the covers,  not `String#replace()` (if you paid attention to the stacktrace, you would also have seen it).

Comment: Stacktrace was added after my answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Just to demonstrate with one backslash:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String text = "text\\";

        System.out.println(text.replaceAll("\\\\","/"));
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I need a solution that will work in an EL expression :(.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I found out how to make it work with EL expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TempClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.next();
        System.out.println("before : "+str);
        String newstr = str.replace("\\", "/");
        System.out.println("after  : "+newstr);
    }
}
```

When I provide input as text\\ I get output as text//

```
before : text\\
after  : text//
```