# javax.faces.el.ReferenceSyntaxException: Functions not supported in expressions. Function: fn:replace

Tags: jsp, jsf, el

I'm trying to replace parts of a string in a JSP file in Alfresco (you can find it [there](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/web-client/source/web/jsp/roles/manage-content-users.jsp)).

More specifically, I want to display more information after the "fullName" on line 54. The information I need is stored in r.id as a string of the form "GROUP_something", where I want the "something". I can display the r.id without issues, as in the snippet below, but as soon as I try to use fn:replace to remove the GROUP_ prefix then it breaks down.

Original:

```
<h:outputText id="user-txt" value="#{r.fullName}" rendered="#{r.isGroup}" />
```

Works as well:

```
<h:outputText id="user-txt" value="#{r.fullName} (#{r.id})" rendered="#{r.isGroup}" />
```

Not working:

```
<h:outputText id="user-txt" value="#{r.fullName} (#{fn:replace(r.id, 'GROUP_', '')})" rendered="#{r.isGroup}" />
```

Full code: http://pastebin.com/w8AXWUH1

The full stack trace is as follows:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /jsp/dialog/container.jsp at line 194

191: 
192: 
193: 
194: " />
195: 
196: 
197: 


Stacktrace:
caused by:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /jsp/dialog/container.jsp at line 194

191: 
192: 
193: 
194: " />
195: 
196: 
197: 


Stacktrace:
caused by:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.faces.FacesException: Exception while calling encodeEnd on : {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /jsp/dialog/container.jsp][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm,Id: dialog][Class: javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer,Id: dialog-body][Class: org.alfresco.web.ui.common.component.UIPanel,Id: users-panel][Class: org.alfresco.web.ui.common.component.data.UIRichList,Id: users-list][Class: org.alfresco.web.ui.common.component.data.UIColumn,Id: _idJsp17][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText,Id: user-txt]}
caused by:
javax.faces.FacesException: Exception while calling encodeEnd on : {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /jsp/dialog/container.jsp][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm,Id: dialog][Class: javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer,Id: dialog-body][Class: org.alfresco.web.ui.common.component.UIPanel,Id: users-panel][Class: org.alfresco.web.ui.common.component.data.UIRichList,Id: users-list][Class: org.alfresco.web.ui.common.component.data.UIColumn,Id: _idJsp17][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText,Id: user-txt]}
caused by:
javax.faces.FacesException: Could not retrieve value of component with path : {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /jsp/dialog/container.jsp][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm,Id: dialog][Class: javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer,Id: dialog-body][Class: org.alfresco.web.ui.common.component.UIPanel,Id: users-panel][Class: org.alfresco.web.ui.common.component.data.UIRichList,Id: users-list][Class: org.alfresco.web.ui.common.component.data.UIColumn,Id: _idJsp17][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText,Id: user-txt]}
caused by:
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Cannot get value for expression '#{r.fullName} (#{fn:replace(r.id, 'GROUP_', '')})'
caused by:
javax.faces.el.ReferenceSyntaxException: Functions not supported in expressions. Function: fn:replace
```

I can't understand this error, as other answers (eg [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492569/jsf-how-to-replace-in-a-string) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901875/how-can-i-manipulate-a-string-in-a-jsf-tag)) advocate this exact method.

I also added the function taglib:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```

in the header.

Any help appreciated!

**Edit**: more info about the environment: I'm using the "bundle" version of Alfresco, using Tomcat 7.0.30 as a container. The following versions of the libraries are used:

- **JSF** Apache MyFaces v1.1.8 (myfaces-api-1.1.8.jar and myfaces-impl-1.1.8.jar)
- **JSP** Tomcat's built-in Jasper (jasper.jar)
- **EL** I *think* it's Tomcat's built-in Jasper-EL (through el-api.jar and jasper-el.jar), **although** Alfresco also bundles commons-el.jar (with Specification-Version: 2.0 and Implementation-Version: 1.0)

Comment: show complete jsp page code

Comment: Never seen this one before. Which JSF impl/version? EL impl/version? Try `<h:panelGroup id="user-txt"><h:outputText value="#{...}"/> <h:outputText value="#{...}"/></h:panelGroup>` instead.

Comment: Hi BalusC, I tried wrapping the outputText in panelGroup, but the error stayed the same. I updated the post with more information about the libraries version. Thanks for looking into it :)

Comment: Take a look https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/MNT-6303

Comment: Did you write the `<h:outputText value>` in such way that it represents the sole individual EL expression? Wrapping in panel group is not by itself the key, it's just in order to print the desired `<span>` with `id`. So, write your code like this: `<h:panelGroup id="user-txt" rendered="#{r.isGroup}"><h:outputText value="#{r.fullName}" /> (<h:outputText value="#{fn:replace(r.id, 'GROUP_', '')}" />)</h:panelGroup>`